# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a hibernate JPA project and I'm facing the above mentioned exception, it's telling that my SQL syntax is not good almost I'm pretty sure of my hibernate configuration with my MySQL database, can anyone help me figure out what's the problem please ? Here is some code:

**UsersHome.java**

```
public class UsersHome {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UsersHome.class);

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "saddem")
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("saddem");
    private EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

    public void persist(Users transientInstance) {
        log.debug("persisting Users instance");
        try {
            entityManager.persist(transientInstance);
            log.debug("persist successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("persist failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public void remove(Users persistentInstance) {
        log.debug("removing Users instance");
        try {
            entityManager.remove(persistentInstance);
            log.debug("remove successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("remove failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public Users merge(Users detachedInstance) {
        log.debug("merging Users instance");
        try {
            Users result = entityManager.merge(detachedInstance);
            log.debug("merge successful");
            return result;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("merge failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public Users findById(Integer id) {
        log.debug("getting Users instance with id:" + id);
        try {
            Users instance = entityManager.find(Users.class, id);
            log.debug("get successful");
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
        // Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("users.findById");
        // query.setParameter("userid", id);
        // Users us=(Users) query.getSingleResult();
        // return us;
    }

    public List<Users> findAll() {
        log.debug("getting all User instances");
        try {
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select u from Users u");
            List<Users> usersList = (List<Users>) query.getResultList();
            log.debug("findAll successful");
            return usersList;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("findAll failed", re);
            return new ArrayList<Users>();
        }
        // Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("users.findAll");
        // List<Users> usersList = (List<Users>) query.getResultList();
        // return usersList;
    }
}
```

**Users.java**

```
@Entity
//@NamedQuery(name="users.findById",query="SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userid = :userid")
//@NamedQuery(name="users.findAll",query="SELECT  FROM Users u")
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "user")
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer userid;
    private Address address;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Address address, String username, String password,
        String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
        this.address = address;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserid() {
        return this.userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "addressid")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", length = 64)
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Users [userid=" + userid + ", username=" + username
            + ", password=" + password + ", firstname=" + firstname
            + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((firstname == null) ? 0 : firstname.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lastname == null) ? 0 : lastname.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((password == null) ? 0 : password.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((userid == null) ? 0 : userid.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Users other = (Users) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
            return false;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        if (firstname == null) {
            if (other.firstname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstname.equals(other.firstname))
            return false;
        if (lastname == null) {
            if (other.lastname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastname.equals(other.lastname))
            return false;
        if (password == null) {
            if (other.password != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!password.equals(other.password))
            return false;
        if (userid == null) {
            if (other.userid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!userid.equals(other.userid))
            return false;
        if (username == null) {
            if (other.username != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

**MainTest.java**

```
public class MainTest {

    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UsersHome dao = new UsersHome() ;
        Users us = dao.findById(1);
        System.out.println("-Livre :"+us.getFirstname());
    }
}
```

**==> exception:**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Hibernate: select users0_.userid as userid1_1_0_, users0_.addressid as addressi7_1_0_, users0_.email as email2_1_0_, users0_.firstname as firstnam3_1_0_, users0_.lastname as lastname4_1_0_, users0_.password as password5_1_0_, users0_.username as username6_1_0_ from user.user.users users0_ where users0_.userid=?
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1694)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1141)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1068)
    at com.sad.db.dao.UsersHome.findById(UsersHome.java:72)
    at com.sad.db.dao.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:21)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4120)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1066)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:951)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1110)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.users users0_ where users0_.userid=1' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.users users0_ where users0_.userid=1' at line 1 <--

I cant find where that sql statement gets created but it doesn't look like that's what's indented.

Comment: so ? what am i supposed to do , you have any suggestion  ?